# d3.js zoom without overflow

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force directed graph with fixed nodes. I have allowed zoom in the graph :

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
         .on("tick", tick);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0, 50])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(zoom);

var graphGroup = svg.append("g")
                  .attr("height", graphHeight)
                  .attr("width", graphWidth)
                  .attr("class", "graph-group")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")");

graphGroup.append("rect")
                  .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("y", 0)
                  .attr("height", graphHeight)
                  .attr("class", "graph-limit")
                  .attr("width", graphWidth);

...

function zoomed() {
    graphContainer.attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

I would like to limit the `zoom` (`scale` and `translation`) of the graph within the rectangle with class "`graph-limit`".
I've tried to put `overflow:hidden` in style, but without success.
Any idea ?

**EDIT :**
Here a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Lxc43v8d/20/

Comment: can you fiddle your work?

Comment: Why don't you adjust the `scaleExtent` values in such way that the graph will not be scaled than the expected limit?

Comment: @Fawzan, i'm doing it.

Comment: @Gilsha, because the size of the graph is almost the same as the rectangle

Comment: If so, set the maximum value to 1. Something like `zoom.scaleExtent([0,1])`

Comment: @Gilsha, I can't because the user must be able to zoom on specific part of the graph

Comment: hhmm.. ok..Have to find some other way then. This link may be helpful. http://computationallyendowed.com/blog/2013/01/21/bounded-panning-in-d3.html

Comment: Thank you. I have added a jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it.

Use clip path with dimension exactly same as that off the rectangle:

```
//make a clip path
svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
        .attr("id", "clip")
        .append("svg:rect")
        .attr("id", "clip-rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
                  .attr("y", 0)
                  .attr("height", graphHeight)
                  .attr("width", graphWidth);
```

To the group which holds the rectangle all nodes and links add the clip path like this

```
var graphGroup = svg.append("g")
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")//add the clip path
                  .attr("height", graphHeight)
                  .attr("width", graphWidth)
                  .attr("class", "graph-group");
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/Lxc43v8d/22/)

Hope this helps!